# Can't parse JSON parameter

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am using WebAPI to get the POST message.  The body of the POST message:
`{"datetime":"2017-01-06T20:40:44.2401244Z","filename":"somefilename.csv","datasourcename":"MyDataSource","error":"The uploaded file has no tags."}`

The header included with the POST:
`Content-type: application/json`

My action method that handle the message:
[HttpPost]

```
public void SaveMessage([FromBody] string msg)
{ 
    MyModel w = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(msg);
    db.MyModels.Add(w);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

My question is how do I encode the JSON so that I can parse it?  I can't change the incoming message.  What can I do in my method so that I can read it?  Right now `msg` always give me `null`.

Comment: have you tried json.stringify?

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify({....})` but your method should be `public void SaveMessage([FromBody] SomeModel model)` where `SomeModel` contains properties `DateTime datetime`, `string filename` etc

Comment: @StephenMuecke Where do I put the `JSON.stringify`?  There's no page to display.  It's just I receive a message, I put it in the database.

Comment: How are you posting that data to that method? (I assumed you were making an ajax call). If the `content-type` is `application/json`, the the data needs to be stringified

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have a web hook on a cloud application.  Whenever my upload fail, they will send the JSON message.  All I do is store the message in the database.

Comment: Are you sure its not already stringified? Try changing the method signature to `public void SaveMessage([FromBody] MyModel model)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I did that before but without the `[FromBody]` and it didn't work.  It works now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you have no control over the data being sent, then as suggested in the comments, make sure you have a model that matches the desired object model of the JSON

```
public class MyModel {
    public DateTime datetime { get; set; }
    public string filename { get; set; }
    public string datasourcename { get; set; }
    public string error { get; set; }
}
```

And take advantage of the model binding capability of the Web API framework and let the action bind a strongly typed model from the body of the request.

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult SaveMessage([FromBody] MyModel model) {
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {
        db.MyModels.Add(w);
        if(db.SaveChanges() > 0)
            return Ok();
    }
    return BadRequest();
}
```

If there are any issues with saving the message the action will return HTTP Status Code 400 Bad Request, otherwise it will return HTTP Status Code 200 OK.